# Dynamic Bootstrap accordion display issue when first-of-type and last-of-type is the same child

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, accordion

When creating Accordion children objects dynamically, in most cases you have multiple children, so first-of-type and last-of-type work great. There is an instance where Accordion only has 1 child. In such case, that 1 child is both first-of-type and last-of-type, causing weird CSS to display (without radius and no bottom border):

```
.accordion > .card:last-of-type {
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
}
.accordion > .card:first-of-type {
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
}
```

How do you fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to resolve this is to add CSS that will cover 1 child scenario, and undo the previous CSS:

```
.accordion > .card:first-of-type:last-of-type {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
```

Make sure this code is placed after bootstrap.css.